# Oracle dbms_crypto for PKCS7

Tags: .net, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, dbms-crypto

My requirement is to peform the dbms_crypto tool to decrypt the encrypted column from a table which is encrypted from DOTNET end.
It looks that PKCS7 method is used in dotnet where in I am unable to find corresponding padding in Oracle side; PKCS5 is available.

Can anyone help me if this is possible from plsql side to get the required values:

Dot Net encryption code given below:

```
private static void Encrypt()
{
    byte[] toEncryptArray = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ID:5031743749436704");
    byte[] keyArray = new byte[16] {
     34,
     170,
     219,
     38,
     68,
     125,
     135,
     181,
     80,
     177,
     85,
     164,
     215,
     100,
     250,
     208 };
    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes.
    //We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)
    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    //padding mode(if any extra byte added)
    tdes.IV = new byte[8];
    tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateEncryptor();
    //transform the specified region of bytes array to resultArray
    byte[] resultArray =
      cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0,
      toEncryptArray.Length);
    //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor
    tdes.Clear();
    //Return the encrypted data into unreadable string format
    string enCryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
}

private static void Decrypt()
{
    byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String("T71mQdBbEwnk5kZKAc+16kgsrln4EkCJ");

    byte[] keyArray = new byte[16] {
     34,
     170,
     219,
     38,
     68,
     125,
     135,
     181,
     80,
     177,
     85,
     164,
     215,
     100,
     250,
     208 };
    //string s = Convert.ToBase64String(keyArray);

    //string s1 = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(keyArray);

    //string s3 = UTF32Encoding.UTF32.GetString(keyArray);

    //string s4 = UTF7Encoding.UTF7.GetString(keyArray);


    TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
    //set the secret key for the tripleDES algorithm
    tdes.Key = keyArray;
    //mode of operation. there are other 4 modes. 
    //We choose ECB(Electronic code Book)

    tdes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
    //padding mode(if any extra byte added)
    //tdes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

    tdes.IV = new byte[8];

    ICryptoTransform cTransform = tdes.CreateDecryptor();

    byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(
                         toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);
    //Release resources held by TripleDes Encryptor                
    tdes.Clear();



    //return the Clear decrypted TEXT
    string decryptedString = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);

    string s2 = Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray); // Base 64 string of raw cc token


    var str = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(new byte[8]);

}
```

Oracle try given below:

```
--encrypt
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
     l_encrypted   RAW(128);
BEGIN
     l_encrypted := dbms_crypto.encrypt(src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw('ID:5031743749436704'), 
                                        typ => dbms_crypto.des3_cbc_pkcs5, 
                                        key => utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('IqrbJkR9h7VQsVWk12T60A==') ) 
                                        );

     dbms_output.put_line( UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(utl_encode.base64_encode(l_encrypted),'AL32UTF8'));
END;
/
/*
actual result:      VOsHqOuCJUSVYMta4Bz2tSe/aMDN+Ol9
expected result:    oCQBWzcu9gCYmxf0kL3oTgkX/K8UVk/t
*/


--decrypt
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
     l_decrypted RAW(128);
BEGIN
      l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt(src => utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_RAW('oCQBWzcu9gCYmxf0kL3oTgkX/K8UVk/t')),
                                        typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.des3_cbc_pkcs5,
                                        key => utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw('IqrbJkR9h7VQsVWk12T60A==') )
                                        );
      dbms_output.put_line( UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(l_decrypted,'AL32UTF8'));
END;
/

/*
actual result: 

Error report -
ORA-28817: PL/SQL function returned an error.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO_FFI", line 67
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_CRYPTO", line 44
ORA-06512: at line 4
28817. 00000 -  "PL/SQL function returned an error."
*Cause:    A PL/SQL function returned an error unexpectedly.
*Action:   This is an internal error. Enable tracing to find more
           information. Contact Oracle customer support if needed.
*Document: NO

expected result: ID:5031743749436704
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

PKCS7 is not supported by Oracle's DBMS_CRYPTO package.

[Here](http://matthewjlittle.com/2011/07/02/plsql-pkcs-7-padding/) is an option for you.

Comment: Thanks and I have tried even using this, this will do the padding / trimming of source data; but how would I provide the parameter for "typ" ? and how can I resolve the error while decrypting ? the post did not give much details on that.

Comment: @ajmalmhd04, the `typ` parameter just tells `dbms_crypto` what type of encryption to use. Since the suggested option does not involve the use of `dbms_crypto`, and only supports one type of encryption (PKCS7) there's no reason or need to specify the type.

Comment: Thanks Mark and @Jeffrey for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark said, PKCS7 is not currently supported by `dbms_crypto`.

To answer your question about why your PKCS5 code failed with the (admittedly unhelpful) error "A PL/SQL function returned an error unexpectedly.", the problem in your case is that the functions you are calling to convert the values for the `src` and `key` parameters are not quite correct. You don't need to call `utl_encode.base64_decode` to convert the raw key values. Also, the value you pass to `src` should be the reverse of how you converted from the original encrypted raw into a string - i.e. to display the encrypted value, you called `utl_encode.base64_encode` followed by `utl_i18n.raw_to_char`. To convert the resulting string back into a raw, you need to do the exact reverse - i.e. call `utl_i18n.string_to_raw` followed by `utl_encode.base64_decode`.

Here is a working example:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
     l_encrypted   RAW(128);
     l_decrypted   RAW(128);
     l_key         RAW(128);
BEGIN
     l_key := utl_raw.cast_to_raw('IqrbJkR9h7VQsVWk12T60A==');

     l_encrypted := dbms_crypto.encrypt(src => utl_raw.cast_to_raw('ID:5031743749436704'), 
                                        typ => dbms_crypto.des3_cbc_pkcs5, 
                                        key => l_key
                                        );

     dbms_output.put_line(
       UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(
         utl_encode.base64_encode(l_encrypted),'AL32UTF8'));

     l_encrypted := utl_encode.base64_decode(
       utl_i18n.string_to_raw('tKQyG9kMqEMyv28q/dDXfGuWbf+Dnday','AL32UTF8'));

     dbms_output.put_line(
       UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(
         utl_encode.base64_encode(l_encrypted),'AL32UTF8'));

     l_decrypted := dbms_crypto.decrypt(src => l_encrypted,
                                        typ => DBMS_CRYPTO.des3_cbc_pkcs5,
                                        key => l_key
                                        );

     dbms_output.put_line( UTL_I18N.RAW_TO_CHAR(l_decrypted,'AL32UTF8'));
END;
/

tKQyG9kMqEMyv28q/dDXfGuWbf+Dnday
tKQyG9kMqEMyv28q/dDXfGuWbf+Dnday
ID:5031743749436704
```

[LiveSQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/hekj3ct55p0q19jdxxgyphphj)

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey for your help, but unfortunately the solution wont help in my requirement. So we have planned to take this activity from client side itself.

Comment: Well of course it won't - it was clear you needed a solution for PKCS7. I was just answering your question.